# Scikit-learn including strings in Supervised Learning results

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

I have a large dataset with first and last names as well as an identifier string that I do not want to include in the actual training of a classifier. I do however want to associate these names with their respective data entries. Each row is defined in a csv file as follows:

```
firstname(string),lastname(string),identifier(string),(int),(int),(int),...(int)
```

I have the dataInput with multiple rows of the data above, and a targetList with 1's and 0's pertaining to my result.

```
data = genfromtxt(dataInput, delimiter=',')
answers = genfromtxt(targetList, delimiter = ',')
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
clf = MLPClassifier(solver='lbfgs', alpha=1e-5)
# generate random indices to test
test_idx = random.sample(range(1,8000), 100)
train_target = np.delete(answers, test_idx)
train_data = np.delete(data, test_idx)
test_target = answers[test_idx]
test_data = data[test_idx]
#Code errors out here
clf.fit(train_data, train_target)
clf.predict(test_data)
```

The result is that the dataset becomes a 1D array and does not process the result. Without the strings, this code works. However, I've been requested to include these names and identifiers in my result. How can I format the csv data and tell the classifier to associate the identifying strings and fit the data without fitting the strings?

Comment: I am not able to understand your error. Please explain in more detail, with example code. "Without the strings, this code works", which strings? Scikit need all strings to be converted to numerical before training.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not planning on doing any fancy cross-validation and are basically looking to split the data into train and test sets, below is one way to do it.

Caveats: I'm randomly generating data so I may be working around issues you won't be facing like datatype casting.

Take-away: manually shuffle your data before-hand, use `train_test_split` (from sklearn) and set `shuffle=False`, then slice the numpy datasets to cut out the string columns and pass the numeric to the classifier. The slicing makes this example look ugly which is why I'd personally use pandas.

Alternative way: slightly more advanced but you could use a pipeline and a custom transformer to select the numeric data from the overall data (not shown below).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import bernoulli
import string, random

from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

### making up data, don't need to understand this part ###
size = 10000
fnames = np.array([''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters, k=5)) for i in range(size)])
lnames = np.array([''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters, k=5)) for i in range(size)])
identifier = np.array([''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters, k=2)) for i in range(size)])
rand_ints = np.random.randint(0, 20, (size,10))

data = np.column_stack((fnames, lnames, identifier, rand_ints))
answers = bernoulli.rvs(0.3, size=size)
###---------------------------end----------------------###

np.random.shuffle(data) # an in-place operation

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    data, answers, test_size=0.10, random_state=42, shuffle=False)

clf = MLPClassifier(solver='lbfgs', alpha=1e-5)
clf.fit(X_train[:, 3:].astype('int16'), y_train)
score = clf.score(X_test[:, 3:].astype('int16'), y_test)
print('Test score: {}'.format(score))

pred = clf.predict(X_test[:, 3:].astype('int16'))

X_train_result = np.column_stack((X_train[:, :3], y_train, clf.predict(X_train[:, 3:].astype('int16'))))
X_test_result = np.column_stack((X_test[:, :3], y_test, clf.predict(X_test[:, 3:].astype('int16'))))
```

Output from above example:

```
Test score: 0.694
>>> X_train_result
array([['TGOxK', 'dOKWj', 'Bn', '1', '0'],
       ['GmqwM', 'iucDx', 'qX', '1', '0'],
       ['VXdJG', 'SJRVg', 'Nl', '1', '0'],
       ...,
       ['jClSD', 'ABkrp', 'zZ', '0', '0'],
       ['IoLrh', 'HiHLI', 'oU', '1', '0'],
       ['zzyGR', 'UCpRT', 'xg', '0', '0']], dtype='<U11')
>>> X_test_result
array([['zOLmZ', 'OMVrx', 'AS', '1', '0'],
       ['wfIsi', 'zEMEE', 'PU', '1', '0'],
       ['wHVtq', 'fbtMK', 'UD', '1', '0'],
       ...,
       ['paBoM', 'HVjpF', 'Ez', '0', '0'],
       ['ZivWN', 'VrHhm', 'FL', '0', '0'],
       ['WnHLw', 'hakoK', 'Qv', '0', '0']], dtype='<U11')
```

- First column: first name
- Second column: last name
- Third column: identifier
- Fourth column: true answer (y true)
- Fifth column: predicted answer (y pred)